# cache line retrieval and performance on large data structure

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, caching, g++

Let's suppose I have a very big data structure that is much larger than the cache line of my hardware (see sample below). Let's suppose that I want to

1. read and write `memb_one_`  located at the first cache line
2. then I want to read and write`memb_forty_` located 2 cache line after.
3. now I might want also to read and write members located in the second cache line i.e. the one in the middle line `memb_ten_`. This doesn't happen always.

So I need to frequently perform step 1. and step 2. but not always step 3. Unfortunately I cannot change the layout of the structure.

My question is the following: after step 1. and step 2., is the second cache line i.e. the one in the middle retrieved at all from the memory into L1?

As far as I understood the cache lines retrieved in L1 are only the one 'touched' by reading/writing struct members located in them. That would mean essentially that only a portion of the instance of a structure would be availble in L1.

If my understanding is correct, is there anyway to force the request of all the 3 cache lines? I would like to avoid the cache miss I would get by writing on the second cache line when I need to.

If there's no such mechanism do you think that I could benefit from using a background thread sharing the same cache and doing frequent reading of those instances to keep the cache lines 'hot'? This thread would never write to to avoid false sharing effect or excessive data bus traffic.

```
 struct VeryBigStruct 
 { 
   // first cahce line..
   int memb_one_;
   ...

   // second cahce line..
   int memb_ten_;
   ...

   // third cache line
   int memb_forty_;
   ...
 }
```

I am using `g++ 4.7 and 4.9` on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the second cache line is not guaranteed to be in L1 cache after you touch the first and the third ones. But it could be there, if it is accessed frequently enough.

A background thread might only help to get your data into L1 cache if it runs in the same physical core as your main thread. You could set CPU affinity for your threads to achieve this effect.

In gcc there is a builtin functions to prefetch a memory address to cache,
it is called like this:

```
__builtin_prefetch(&your_struct_ptr->memb_ten_, 1, 3);
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
...
_mm_prefetch(&your_struct_ptr->memb_ten_, _MM_HINT_ET0);
```

See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html
and here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524263

[ I presume you use x86 or x86-64 architecture. ]

Comment: @Alexey: Thanks a lot!  I was thinking that I night put that call in an existing thread (on the same core) that tries to acquire a mutex via 'try_lock'. If try_lock doesn't succeed it will call that __builtin_prefetch

Comment: Prefetch works the best if you call it first, then spend a few CPU cycles on something else, giving CPU the time to execute your request in the background, then you get back to really use prefetched data.